# How to implement puts() function?

Tags: c

I have tried to implement the puts function.It in actual returns a value but i cant get what should it return.please check my code and guide me further

```
/* implementation of puts function */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void puts(string)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;    ;i++)
    {
        if(string[i]=='\0')
        {
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("%c",string[i]);

    }

}
```

Comment: @fahad:  Please format your code when posting a question.  You can do so by indenting it four spaces.

Comment: There's an if(...) break in there, so yes, his loop actually will quit.

Comment: What is your goal behind (re)implementing `puts()`? Are you trying to log all calls to it, something of that nature?

Comment: I would suggest putc(string[i]) instead of printf.

Comment: Also if you are trying to go for efficiency, try using `putchar()` instead of `printf("%c",...)`.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/putchar/

Comment: @Marius Gedminas `putc()` requires you pass it a character, as well as a file stream.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/putc/

Comment: If you want to use printf you can write printf("%s\n" string);.

Comment: My bad, I meant putchar(...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See comments in code.

```
int puts(const char *string)
{
    int i = 0;
   while(string[i])  //standard c idiom for looping through a null-terminated string
    {
        if( putchar(string[i]) == EOF)  //if we got the EOF value from writing the char
        { 
            return EOF;
        }
        i++;
    }
   if(putchar('\n') == EOF)  //this will occur right after we quit due to the null terminated character.
   {
       return EOF;
   }
   return 1; //to meet spec.
}
```

And, as an aside - I've written the equivalent of putc, puts several different times in relation to developing on embedded systems. So it's not always just a learning  exercise. :)

Comment on EOF: It is a POSIX constant from stdio.h.
In my Linux stdio.h, I have this definition:

```
/* End of file character.
   Some things throughout the library rely on this being -1.  */
#ifndef EOF
# define EOF (-1)
#endif
```

That definition code is GPL 2.1.

Comment: Can you tell me more about EOF? is it a constant?

Comment: @fahad: Yes sir. see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/EOF/ . On a recent Ubuntu box, EOF was #define'd in stdio.h as -1.

Comment: I have only written the code off the top of my head, not compiled it. :-)

Comment: You should also return `EOF` if putting the `'\n'` character results in `EOF`.

Comment: You mean I can never #define a macro named EOF as -1 without violating the GPL?  That kind of sucks.

Comment: @Dan: I wanted to note the license of the code I copied. But, since you take that interpretation, I'd like to license `int i = 0` to myself, with a cost of $100 per use, payable to me in unmarked bills..

Comment: EOF is also in Standard C. not just posix.

Answer (score 0):

What's `string` supposed to be? You should [define your function better](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Functions), try:

```
void my_puts(const char *string)
```

instead of

```
void puts(string)
```

As noted in the link I included, you need to specify the data type of the argument you're passing (in your example `string`) and you cannot use the name of a function which has already been defined (i.e. `puts` ).

Comment: is there even a default type for function arguments?  there must be or else this wouldn't have compiled for the OP.

Comment: @Kevin: I believe in K&R C, default type for function args was 'int'.

Comment: it's been a LONG time since I've read K&R but I do believe you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual page:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fputc(int c, FILE *stream);
int fputs(const char *s, FILE *stream);
int putc(int c, FILE *stream);
int putchar(int c);
int puts(const char *s);
```

**Return Value**

`fputc()`, `putc()` and `putchar()` return the character written as an unsigned char cast to an int or `EOF` on error.

`puts()` and `fputs()` return a non-negative number on success, or `EOF` on error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, stdio's puts() returns a non-negative number on success, or EOF on error.

Comment: There's nothing missing; note the break statement within the if.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said, I am personally opposed to redefining standard library functions. However, if you absolutely must (e.g. for a homework assignment), and your compiler is complaining about conflicting types for 'puts', try putting this at the top:

```
#define puts _puts
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#undef puts
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any point in implementing puts!
anyway, you should read the specs of puts so you can make it.

this may help

```
int myputs(char* s)
{
   int x = printf("%s\n", s);
   return (x > 0) ? x : EOF;
}
```

you should include stdio.h so you can use printf and EOF.

Note that this is not EXACT implementation of puts, because on error puts sets an error indicator and do some other stuff.

More details about puts, [here](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/puts.html).